# Multiple images on background using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I don't know if someone ask this question before.I am working on MVC + Security application and done all the parts, but there is some minor issues in display page, below is my .css file's snippet

```
body{  
    background-color:#D8D8D8;
    background-image:url("../css/logo.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right top;
    margin-right:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    }
```

This is my company's logo. Now I have to add another image at (position:right bottom) of the page. Can any body suggest how to do it? or it is not possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `background-image` property can [accept a comma-separated list of values in CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image), but not all browsers support it yet:

```
body{  
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    background-image: url("../css/logo.gif"), url("../css/other-logo.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: right top, right bottom;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

If you need broad support the usual approach is to add an extra wrapper element.

Comment: See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20background) for browser support. IE<9 don't support multiple backgrounds, but basically everything else does.

Comment: CSS3 Pie supports multiple backgrounds, and I use them with it all the time. http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
   body { background-image: url(image_1.jpg), url(image_2.jpg);
          background-position:top right, bottom right;
        }
```